# Enable Virtualization Technology RDP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Yesterday I bought RDP from Google Cloud with Specifications
** 1 GPU - NVIDIA Tesla P4 / T4
6 core - 16 gb ram **

so i downloaded the android emulator and run but i can't change the emulator settings (default 1 core with ram 3072mb). They say I need to enable VT so I can edit the settings, and I search on google and all the tutorial is to go to BIOS. Then how do you enter the BIOS in RDP?

thank you

Comment: This is purely a guess ... but if your application needs virtualization, it may be that you have to explicitly switch on VT support in the compute engine.   Here is a recipe.... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances